# How to enable force ssl on AWS Aurora Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, configuration, aws, ssl, aurora

In AWS's direct postgres offering RDS Postgres, you can require SSL by setting the parameter group item `rds.force_ssl` to 1.

This is as per the RDS postgres documentation:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.SSL

However Aurora Postgres does not have this parameter item, and there is no ability to add new parameters either.  How do you turn on require ssl for an Aurora instance?

I can see in the Aurora version that it supports SSL:

```
create extension sslinfo;
select ssl_is_used();
select ssl_cipher();
```

And I can optionally connect via ssl:

```
psql -h my-ssl-test1.cwzhlddlylx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -p 5432
-U myuser -d mydb sslrootcert=rds-ca-2015-root.pem sslmode=verify-full
```

Answer (score 10):

For Aurora Postgres, there's two relevant [cluster-level parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/AuroraPostgreSQL.Reference.html) (note they're not instance-level parameters): `rds.force_ssl` and `ssl`. I haven't tested this myself but you should be able to modify them in the usual way using [DB Parameter Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.html#USER_WorkingWithParamGroups.Modifying).

Comment: I applied this in the UI but needed to reboot the instances in order to be in effect. I don't know of another way though :/